# executing jhipster war file exception

Tags: jhipster

while running java -jar "warfilename" gives AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes :
 org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException:
 None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}].but the app is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which profile you use to run your app. In dev, JHipster embeds an elasticsearch instance in your app, in prod profile it uses an external cluster that you must have setup and configured in application-prod.yml.

Comment: how to setup external cluster ? Are we suppose to install elastic search in local machine and set node and cluster name and same cluster name and node name  give in application-prod.yml?

Comment: This is another question you should open and targeted to elasticsearch experts.